# How to see if values are in the same "line" within an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Not sure how to approach this problem, but I want to see if two values are in the same 'line'

```js
var inventory_needed = [
    { section: "hardware",          supplies: "hammers"                       },
    { section: "plumbing",          supplies: "pipes"                         },
    { section: "garden",            supplies: "grass seeds"                   },
    { section: "cleaning supplies", supplies: ["hand sanitizer", "detergent"] },
    { section: "appliances",        supplies: ["fridges", "dishwashers"]      } 
];
```

psuedocode of what I want to try to attempt

```js
if(section.value && supplies.value in the same line) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}

//example 1
if("appliances" && "fridges" in the same line) {
    return true; //would return true
}
else {
    return false;
}

//example 2
if("plumbing" && "fridges" in the same line) {
    return true; 
}
else {
    return false; //would return false
}
```

Comment: How you pass all value of array ? with `forEach/filter/map` ? edit your question with an example with tool `[<>]`

Comment: What do you mean by "line"? You mean in the same object? (Since each of your objects is on a single line of code.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah that's what I am trying to attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By in the same line, you seem to mean defined within the same object in the array. If that's correct, the way to do that is like this:

```
function inTheSameLine(section, supplies){
    return inventory_needed.some(obj => {
        return obj.section === section && (
            obj.supplies === supplies || (
               Array.isArray(obj.supplies) && obj.supplies.includes(supplies)
            )
        );
    });
}
```

The JavaScript array `some` function returns true if any of  the array elements satisfy the condition.

Comment: good answer. But one small mistake.One breaket is missing.  `(obj => { ... }` <-- the last one

Comment: Beware that strings have an includes method too, so you'll want to explicitly check for an array.